# Parse Audio Src with JSoup

Tags: java, parsing, jsoup

I'm attempting to parse to following code and trying to extract the src attribute from the Audio element.

```
<div id="jquery_jplayer_1" class="jp-jplayer" style="width: 0px; height: 0px;">
    <img id="jp_poster_0" style="width: 0px; height: 0px; display: none;">
        <audio id="jp_audio_0" preload="none" src="http://www.testurl.com/mp3embed-zg3t2s8n2ofl.mp3">
        </audio>
</div>
```

I've attempted to parse it using the following code with no success

```
  Element link = doc.select("audio").first();
```

and

```
  Element link = doc.select("#jp_audio_0");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
String html = \\your html..
Document doc =Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(html);

//Selects first "audio" element with id of "jp_audio_0" and gets the "src" attribute.
String src = doc.select("audio#jp_audio_0").first().attr("src");

System.out.println(src);
```

Comment: I just tried it out at with the site http://www.hotnewhiphop.com/wale-the-pessimist-feat-j-cole-feat-j-cole-new-song.1963758.html and no luck. I'm guessing the full html isnt generated with jsoup?

Comment: @MrToast, Looking at the source of that page at that link, I don't see any `<audio>` element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String src = doc.select("audio[id=jp_audio_0]").first().attr("src");
```